# how to filter out data using filter if its a foreign key?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have two models:

Profile model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  idno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  email=models.CharField(max_length=40)
  username=models.CharField(max_length=30)
  def __str__(self):
    return self.username
```

Connection Request model

```
class ConnectRequest(models.Model):
       idno = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
       sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sender")
       receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="receiver")
       def __str__(self):
           return f"{self.sender} to {self.receiver} "
```

when I am trying to filter out all the data where sender is suppose "XYZ" then its giving me an error on the shell

```
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(sender="XYZ")
```

"idno expected a number but got "xyz"

i have tried all these things but it still didn't work and gave errors

```
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(sender.name="XYZ")
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(Profile.name="XYZ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can try this code snippet

```
from django.db.models import Q
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(Q(sender__name__icontains="XYZ")|Q(sender__username__icontains="XYZ"))
```

Comment: obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(Q(sender__username__icontains="XYZ"))    this worked perfectly fine thanks !!! can you please explain?

Comment: In this query, ConnectionRequest Model filtering the sender username or sender name

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(sender__name="XYZ")
```

or this :

```
obj=ConnectRequest.objects.filter(sender__name__contains="XYZ") #or also icontains
```

Comment: it didn't give an error but its returning an empty QuerySet

Comment: are you sure you have actual data in the Profile model?